how to solve the script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')?

I get this: Service Worker URL: /mockServiceWorker.js index.tsx:33
Failed to start mock service worker: DOMException: Failed to update a
ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script
('http://localhost:3000/mockServiceWorker.js'): The script has an
unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (anonymous) @ index.tsx:33
Promise.catch (async) ./src/index.tsx @ index.tsx:31 options.factory @
react refresh:6
webpack_require @ bootstrap:22 (anonymous) @ startup:7 (anonymous) @ startup:7

My setup is as follow:
public/index.html & mockServiceWorker.js I already run npx msw init public, clean node_modules and restart but did not fix the issue:https://mswjs.io/docs/integrations/browser#copy-the-worker-script

index.tsx
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import store from './redux/store';
import { App } from './App';
import { worker } from './mocks/mocks';

async function enableMocking() {
  const serviceWorkerUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/mockServiceWorker.js' : `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/mockServiceWorker.js`;

  console.log('Service Worker URL:', serviceWorkerUrl);

  return worker.start({
    serviceWorker: {
      url: serviceWorkerUrl,
    },
    onUnhandledRequest: 'bypass',
  });
}

const rootDiv = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootDiv);

enableMocking()
  .then(() => {
    root.render(
      <ReduxProvider store={store}>
        <App />
      </ReduxProvider>
    );
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Failed to start mock service worker:', error);
    root.render(
      <ReduxProvider store={store}>
        <App />
      </ReduxProvider>
    );
  });


export const API_URL = "/api";


import { FC } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Images } from '../components/pages/images';




const AppRouter:FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Images />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;


why i get the error and what can be the issue here ?

I had similar issue but it was on production build not on local in your webpack configuration add this
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: './public/mockServiceWorker.js',
        },
      ],
    }),
  ]


Since I am using create-react-app, I don't have direct access to the Webpack configuration out of the box, where should i add it then ?

@user19625670 you should eject it if you know what you're doing. Otherwise there is probably a way to just extend it with overriding config.
